# What does this "in" mean here?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

**a cupboard in the wall.**

What does this "In" mean here?
What image comes to mind?

Comment: A built-in cupboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an image with two sorts of cupboard, from [http://thepapermulberry.blogspot.com/2011/07/500-year-old-farmhouse-full-of-french.html]:

[image: Cupboards]

On the right, under the clock, is a dark free-standing cupboard set *against* the wall. On the left is a cupboard *in* the wall—the doors are flush with the wall, and the shelves occupy the space within the thickness of the wall.

Comment: So my sentece there means the one on the left?

Comment: @username901345 Yes.